# 1980s fantasy book with a prophecy involving a doll in a Nativity set

Tags: story-identification, books

Long time ago so recollection is very vague.

The first in a 4-book series I think. Pretty sure the books came out late 80's and early 90's. The book was about 300 pages.

A scene I remember in it is there is a prophecy that the special character will appear after 500 years (maybe) when a baby doll is found in a special Nativity-like set.

Half way through the book someone stumbles into the set and reaches in and finds the doll.
The special person I think is wandering around without his memory after that.

edit:
As far as i can recall it was fantasy and not set on earth.

Comment: Sounds kind of like a Frank Peretti novel, but I haven't found a match yet.

Comment: Doesn't really fit, but Susan Cooper's The Dark is Rising is the second in a quartet, set around Christmas time, and with the coming into power of a special character (the last of the Old Ones).

Comment: @Showsni Maybe OP is conflating The Dark is Rising and The Grey King--in the latter book, Will Stanton does lose his memory of being an Old One for the early part of the book. Series is 5 books though.

Comment: As far as i can recall it was fantasy and not set on earth. Pretty sure it is not Over Sea, Under Stone or one of the frank peretti book. Thanks for the suggestions,